# Dynamic entity creation from a string array

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to retrieve data from azure table storage(Depends on the connection string). I have to create a view model and bind the data to the UI using angular.

I have extracted the column names from the table into a string array.But how do I fill in the data into a view model when I don't know the fields?? or How do I create a dynamic view model from the string array??

Answer (score 0):

So the way to solve this is to create a type provider in an F# library and consume that type provider from C#.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034.aspx

This library already does that with Blobs, Queues and Tables.  The best part is it is written by Isaac Abraham, so it should be solid quality. https://github.com/fsprojects/AzureStorageTypeProvider

If you are stuck with only client code, then perhaps you can create an api that stands between the table storage and the client code that returns an object plus meta data that is useful to you for dynamically generating view models.  For example, try something of this form:

Object: Name,

Properties: 10,

Property1: Name
Property1_Type: type,
Property1_SortOrder: 
etc etc

This should allow you to dynamically generate a view model.